# How to identify whether webservice is implemented using SOAP or RestFul?

Tags: web-services, soap, restful-architecture

I am quite new to this area.

Is it possible to identify webservices is implemented with SOAP or RestFul?
also, will it make any difference for Request (API call) depending on implementation method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, every web service framework have its own separate superior features. Identifying web services is implemented with either SOAP or Restful is totally based on the requirement, performance, standardization, security features as well as customization of the services on the future.

Please follow these links, I hope you will got your answers with these.

https://blogs.oracle.com/milan/entry/web_services_rest_vs_soap

http://predic8.com/axis2-cxf-jax-ws-comparison.htm

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws11/